# Google Cloud Function "[ERROR]: Exception on / [POST]"

Tags: exception, logging, google-cloud-functions

I have this error

> [ERROR]: Exception on / [POST]

as the last entry in the `Log` tab of the Cloud Function after testing the function failed with:

> Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Details:
> 500 Internal Server Error: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sharing this since it surprised me. The log just needs some dozen seconds to really finish the entries. In my case, I went to the `Log` directly after the failed test, and then jumped to `Edit` of the CF right after seeing that log entry error at the bottom, thinking it would be all to gain from the log.

Then I changed my mind, went back to the `Log` tab and saw the real error entry only coming after that `[ERROR]: Exception on / [POST]`.

Not important since you will have another error anyway: I had used `create_engine()` function without the needed module prefix `sqlalchemy.create_engine()`. *(Side-note: Querying your own db does not seem to work anyway in a CF unless you use a VPC connector, do not think from this example that it might be possible)*.